# How to align dynamically generated div's

Tags: php, html

I want to align my divs in two rows.

```
     <div class="row-fluid">        
     <?php

        foreach($role_array as $k =>$v)
        {
            if($k != "bookin_operator" && $k!= "production_manager" && $k != "client" && $k != "admin" )
            {

        ?>


                <div class="span6">  
                    <div class='control-group'>
                        <label for='<?php echo $k;  ?>' class='control-label'><?php  echo $v ;?></label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            <select class='form-control' name='<?php echo $k;  ?>[]' id='<?php echo $k;  ?>' multiple='multiple' size='5'>
                                <?php

                                   foreach($all_datas[$k] as $datas ) 
                                   {

                                        $username = "{$datas->nickname}";

                                        echo "<option value='{$datas->id}'>{$username}</option>";
                                   }

                                ?>

                            </select>
                            <label for="<?php echo $k;  ?>" class="error" style="display:none"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>                         
                </div> 

        <?php
            }

        } 

        ?> 
        </div>
```

I want to 11 similar divs(class="span6"),now the divs displayed like 1st and second in single row bt remaining are in different rows. I want to display it 2 in a row.how it possible??

Comment: try giving width: 50%; and float: left to the span6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap or an equivalent system of grid.

If you want it pure, try this :

```
.span6 {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Example with JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L9drvg8/3/)

Comment: I have a doubt how to adjust its height,because when no of chosen values in the select box,it's alignment(height) change.